# Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith — Order 66

Tags: translation, english-to-german

There is a scene in the third episode of *Star Wars* in which Darth Sidious says

> Execute Order Sixty-Six.

What would be the best way to translate this into German? I am thinking of using ausführen in the Sie-imperative form and Befehl for command/order, as in

> Führen Sie den Befehl sechsundsechzig aus.

Is this correct? I’m having trouble finding the scene from the German-language version of the film, but I wonder how it is translated in that.

Also, the English version of the sentence conveys the ominous tone well — I am worried that my German version, even if it is correct, loses that ominousness.

Comment: I'd use *Weisung* or perhaps *Anweisung* / *Anordnung*, but since I haven't seen the German version of Star Wars, I don't know what the official translation uses.

Comment: Found some subtitles using "Führt die Order 66 aus.", but I don't know if they're matching the German version or if it's just a fan translation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Yes, that's the exact text of the dub. Just checked it on Youtube ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your proposal is grammatically correct, yet a real world *Imperator* who is a German native speaker would more likely use:

> Befehl 66 ausführen. (Infinitive)

Or by stating a fact:

> Befehl 66 tritt in Kraft. (Order 66 is in effect)

Comment: And if it's a *German* imperator in a U.S. movie, he would probably say it in a tone of voice that requires an exclamation mark, or several.

Comment: "Befehl 66 tritt in Kraft." would be "Order 66 comes/enters into force/effect". And apart from its legal effect, it would still have to be physically carried out.  
"Order 66 is in effect" means "Befehl 66 *ist* in Kraft."

Answer (score 6):

It's correct.
But I would prefer to write it "66".
The unofficial rule is: Numbers from 13 should be written as a number.

And: If the sentence is rough said, you should use an exclamation mark instead of a point, i.e. if the person shouts it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to make the sentence sound more ominous? When I read the German version in my head it doesn't sound as [fear-inducing as the English version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09n0qd_n4c0) ...

Comment: I've found a german video of this scene. He exactly says "Führt die Order 66 aus." Order is also used in German, with another pronunciation than in English. You can say it instead of "Befehl".

Comment: Interesting. Why is it führt and not führen Sie? Edit: is it the ihr form?

Comment: Yes, it is second-person plural. Don’t know if he uses _duzen_ or _ihrzen_ in general. – The German text used in dubbing/revoicing of films is often rather substandard because lip synchronization is considered more important than a good translation, so as not to make viewers dizzy. Furthermore, it is often done under high pressure of time.

Comment: @chirlu: Besides that, it might also have been done deliberately. I can think of at least two interpretations: One the one hand, this could express that now the clone troopers and Palpatine are the "close buddies", who move against the "others", the "enemies" (the Jedi). As such, the clone troopers are now within Palpatine's personal circle of trusted people who he knows will do anything for him. On the other hand, it could indicate the non-autonomous status of the clone troopers. By invoking Order 66, Palpatine is activating sleeper agents. In this state, clone troopers are not ...

Comment: ... autonomous individuals any more, they are little more than obedient pets to Palpatine (maybe on par with the battle droids, who, if I remember correctly, were never addressed with "Sie", either), and accordingly do not deserve a "Sie".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The second part of my comment (after the dash) was a general statement, I didn’t mean to say specifically that having Palpatine use _ihr_ was inappropriate.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: It is more likely this is the "royal" plural, which is abundantly used in German Star Wars dubbing to make it sound fancier. Nevertheless, I fully agree that Palpatine would surely not address a storm trooper this way. Limitations and restrictions of dubbing have been pointed out correctly by chirlu.

Comment: @bsumirak: "It is more likely (...) I fully agree that Palpatine would surely not (...)" - so, in effect, you are actually saying that it is *very unlikely* that this particular instance is the "royal" plural? ;)

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Haha, no, the second part of my comment you cite here was intended to address the quality of the German dubbing (which is very poor in this case, imho). :)

Answer (score 4):

I am German, and in the movie he said: ”führt die Order 66 aus”, so: execute the order 66